# Trouble with implementing app for different screens on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, dimensions

I am about to publish my first app and I am extremely confused about making it look nice on different screens.

At first I thought mdpi/hdpi/etc. values (dimensions) folders would suffice when I saw that the screen was showing the exact same things on S4 Mini & S6 Edge, hdpi & xxxdpi respectively.

Well, how is this even possible when I haven't specified other than the main dimensions.xml file?

From what I understand from playing with the layout editor on different devices is that screen size matters more (?).

So far I have created a mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi folder but it seems that that's far from enough.

What other folders should I make? Do I need many layout folders too?

Comment: Could you be more clear about the problem and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this scalable size unit library. It's really easy to use and it will automatically scale your widgets for various screen sizes.

Here's the link if you are interested: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: While this is not the answer to my question, this solution works extremely well.